# How to remove nan and the repeated character from a string list?

Tags: python, list

I have a string list with nan and some repeated characters,  as follows:

```
classes = [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, ' L-glutamate ', nan,
           nan, nan, nan, ' L-lysine ', nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ' dihydroxyacetone',
           nan, nan, nan, ' CoA ', ' CoA ', ' CoA ', ' CoA ',
           ' CoA ', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           ' hydrogen sulfide ', nan, nan, nan, nan, ' CoA ',
           ' CoA ', nan, nan, nan, ' formate ', nan, nan, nan]
```

**I want to remove its nan and the repeated characters.**
**The expected results like:**

```
[' L-glutamate ', ' L-lysine ', ' dihydroxyacetone', ' CoA ', ' hydrogen sulfide ', ' formate ']
```

I tried :

```
nan = float('nan')
ll = [[i for i in j if i == i] for j in classes]
```

and:

```
nan = float('nan')
ll = [[x for x in y if type(x) != float or not math.isnan(x)] for y in classes]
```

Both of them reported Error :
`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

**If it's possible, I also want to** **delete the   (space symbol）at the start and end of every string and reserve the other   (space symbol）**, as follows:

```
['L-glutamate', 'L-lysine', 'dihydroxyacetone', 'CoA', 'hydrogen sulfide', 'formate']
```

Could anyone tell me how to get this?

Comment: Try to split your list comprehension codes into two lines.  It will be clear to see what's going on.

Comment: your `classes` as it is, is not a valid code. Do you mean that all terms of the list are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `filter` + `map`,

```
from math import nan
output = list(set(map(str.strip, filter(lambda x: x is not nan, classes))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this
instead of checking `nan==nan` False you can check `nan in (nan, )`True

```
from math import nan
classes = [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, ' L-glutamate ', nan,
           nan, nan, nan, ' L-lysine ', nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, ' dihydroxyacetone',
           nan, nan, nan, ' CoA ', ' CoA ', ' CoA ', ' CoA ',
           ' CoA ', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
           ' hydrogen sulfide ', nan, nan, nan, nan, ' CoA ',
           ' CoA ', nan, nan, nan, ' formate ', nan, nan, nan]
print([i.strip() for i in classes if i not in (nan, )])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict.fromkeys` to remove the duplicates from the list without changing the order. If the order is not important you can also use `set`. After that use list comprehensions to remove the leading/trailing spaces and filter the `nan`

```
d = dict.fromkeys(classes)
lst = [x.strip() for x in d if x is not nan]
```

or `pop` the `nan` before

```
d = dict.fromkeys(classes)
d.pop(nan)
lst = [x.strip() for x in d]
```

Output

```
['L-glutamate', 'L-lysine', 'dihydroxyacetone', 'CoA', 'hydrogen sulfide', 'formate']
```